# How do I read non-JavaScript files in an NPM dependency?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, npm, path

I have an NPM project called `my-config` that is a dependency of `my-api`. Inside of `my-config`, I have the line:

```
instance.configs.aws = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./etc/aws-config.ini', 'utf-8'));
```

This fetches the `aws-config.ini` in the etc folder of the `my-config` dependency.

However, when I run my-api, it fails with an error, saying that it cannot locate  the ini file:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './etc/aws-config.ini'
```

How do I reference this folder `etc` that exists in my dependency, from my main project that depends on it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try `ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('etc/aws-config.ini', 'utf-8'));` ?

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I prefixed the path with `__dirname` and it seems to be working, but I haven't received a successful runtime validation yet.

```
ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/etc/aws-config.ini', 'utf-8'));
```